# How to find number of items purchased since first registration using SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a list of users and I would like to know how many items each user has purchased since their registration on the platform.

I have in mind the following query, but am not sure if this is the right way to get the # of purchases made since registration for each users.

```
 select userid, count(distinct orderid), order_date
 from user_purchase
 where order_date >= registration_date
group by 1,2
```

Could someone please advise?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  How do you know the registration date?  Can someone make purchases before they register?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi, only registered users can purchase. The desired result should show the average items purchased by each user since their account registration date.

Comment: @adelle Please check this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: It's difficult to answer without knowing table structure, data and expected output.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Tip of today: `GROUP BY` column names, not ordinal positions...

Answer (score 0):

We have done grouping based on userid. Because we wish to know order history for each user.

Try this query:

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(distinct orderid), order_date
FROM user_purchase
WHERE order_date BETWEEN registration_date AND CURDATE() 
GROUP BY user_id;
```